# Laravel Swiftmailer, email is not working on Azure

Tags: php, laravel, email, azure, smtp

My site emailing was working fine on ubuntu. It stopped working after moving to Azure cloud server.
I am using gmail smtp and getting the following error:

```
Swift_TransportException in AbstractSmtpTransport.php line 383:
Expected response code 250 but got code "535", with message "535-5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted. Learn more at
535 5.7.8 https://support.google.com/mail/?p=BadCredentials m143sm21528218qke.18 - gsmtp
"
```

Any sort of help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If user and pass are correct then Step 2 might help https://support.google.com/mail/answer/7126229?p=BadCredentials

> Step 2: Try these troubleshooting steps
>
> Update your email client to the latest version.
>
> Use an App Password: If you use 2-Step Verification, try signing in
>   with an App Password.
>
> **Allow less secure apps: If you don't use 2-Step Verification, you
>   might need to [allow less secure apps](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255) to access your account.**
>
> If you recently changed your Gmail password, you might need to
>   re-enter your Gmail account information or completely repeat your
>   Gmail account setup on your other email client.
>
> **> If the tips above didn't help, visit
>   https://www.google.com/accounts/DisplayUnlockCaptcha and follow the
>   steps on the page.**

Comment: The last step worked. You are life saver man. Thank you @ikurcubic

Comment: Happy to help :) I had similar problems with some older windows mail clients.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the message above, the error might be due to the mismatching of password with account. You can check it first. If it doesn't help, I have no idea either.